# Which is an alternative to R which() for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

`which()` in R returns ids of the cells in a vector that satisfy particular condition (`a>1` in example below) in `which()`. I need similar function for Python to deal with pandas series (data frame columns). Any ideas?

Example in R:

```
a<-c(1,2,1,1,2,3)
which(a>1)
```

output:

> 2 5 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pandas`:

Using `boolean indexing`

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,1,1,2,3])
a[a>1].index
```

```
Int64Index([1, 4, 5], dtype='int64')
```

---

#### `numpy`:

You can achieve same with `np.where`

```
a = np.array([1,2,1,1,2,3])
np.where(a>1)
```

```
(array([1, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)
```